# How to correctly do a many to many query in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, many-to-many

What is the best way to do the next query in an many-to-many relation in Rails 6.

This is my structure:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end

class List < ApplicationRecord    
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
end
```

This is the migration file:

```
class AddContactsListsRelation < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :contacts_lists do |t|
      t.belongs_to :contact
      t.belongs_to :list
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my query:

```
class ContactsLists < ApplicationRecord

  def self.find_with_page(listId, paginationQuery)
    contacts = List.find(listId).contacts
    result = contacts.order(created_at: paginationQuery[:order]).limit(paginationQuery[:page_size])
               .offset(paginationQuery[:page_number] * paginationQuery[:page_size])
    result
  end
end
```

I am not expert on the Rails query API but I think this is a suboptimal way to do two different querys, right?

Comment: Just for your information, better to use `snake_case` for variables because it is some kind of convention https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars

Comment: thank you!!, old habits don't go away easily.

Comment: i'm moving to java (had to...) and have the exact problem, all of my variables are snake_case so my pull requests end up with 2342343 style comments :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have defined the many-to-many relationship, you can easily join the tables.

You need to get contacts, which should be the "base" model to build your query, for example:

```
Contact
  .joins(:lists)
  .where(list_id: listId)
  .order(created_at: paginationQuery[:order]
  .limit(paginationQuery[:page_size])
  .offset(paginationQuery[:page_number] * paginationQuery[:page_size])
```

Comment: glad to help. Also, you have add a `.to_sql` at the end of any AR query to see the sql statement (that's pretty useful, especially when AR makes weird joins)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def self.find_with_page(list_id, pagination_query)
  Contact.joins(:lists)
         .where(lists: { id: list_id })
         .order(created_at: pagination_query[:order])
         .limit(pagination_query[:page_size])
         .offset(pagination_query[:page_number] * pagination_query[:page_size])
end
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to explain how the code works, and why it's the appropriate solution. We're trying to educate so the OP, and others in the future, understand how to solve the problem in other forms.